# Selecting first unique email address in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a  list of UserIds (which is a uniqueidentifier), Names, email addresses and relationships.

Something like

```
SELECT UserId, Name, Email, Relationship FROM Users
```

Sample data would look like:

```
F87B7702-F0EE-11D3-B288-0000B4A488D3  Peter peter@peter.com Member
ZZZZZZZZ-F0EE-11D3-B288-0000B4A488D2  Joan  peter@peter.com Principal
AAAAAAAA-F0EE-11D3-EEEE-0000B4A488D3  Bob   bob@bob.com     Principal
```

Relationship can be either be 'Principal' or 'Member', but a principal user can also be a member.

An email address isn't specific to a user (often a member user will have the same email address as a principal user).

I need to ensure that I only select 1 user per email address so that the same person won't be emailed twice. If there are 2 emails for the same user I need to select the principal record.

What's the easiest way to do this, bearing in mind that you can't do a max on a uniqueidentifier field? For the sample data I gave above I would need to return only the second and third record.

I was leaning towards ordering by Relationship, doing a group by and then max but I don't think that's possible.

Output required is UserId, Name, Email.

Comment: What output columns do you need please? All of them? Or just email address for principle? Can we ignore UserId?

Comment: Output required is UserId, Name, Email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` in ROW_NUMBER() will allow you to choose how to prioritise your emails.  Such as how to deal with an email with no Principle but multiple Members (maybe add `, Name ASC` so the member with the first alphabetically ordered name gets chosen?)

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY email ORDER BY Relationship DESC) AS sequence_id
  FROM
    yourTable
)
  AS sequenced_table
WHERE
  sequence_id = 1
```

Comment: looks good...thought ROW_NUMBER() might be required. thks for the elegant solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understood you, but if you want to get email only once, preffering the principle user this code will do:

```
select UserId, Name, Email, Relationship
from Table
where Relationship='Principle' or ( Relationship='Member' and Email not in
(
select Email
from Table
where Relationship='Principle'
)
)
```

This will give you the second and third lines. If there are more conditions- expand your example.

Comment: If an address has no Principle but multiple Members, this will give multiple addresses.

Comment: If there are multiple members. I didn't see it in the question it just says: often a member user will have the same email address as a principal user. a principal user can also be a member.

Comment: And the idea is that : the same person won't be emailed twice